# Lost network on ubuntu server

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have a virtual machine on Vsphere 5.0 running Ubuntu 12.04 when i put dinamic IP `(/etc/network/interfaces)` iface eth0 inet dhcp
Ubuntu have network and i can do ping to google for example (8.8.8.8)

but when i put static IP and configure resolv.conf

My interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.54
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

it lost the network and i cant do ping to anything...i dont understand where is the problem...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This seems very weird... The fact you are doing this makes me think you are not a novice, but, it looks like it should be correct... so, all I can think of is:

Double check your gateway - is it `192.168.1.1` or could it be `192.168.1.254`  or something else?

In addition, I would not manually edit resolv.conf - add the following line:

`dns-nameservers x.x.x.x` where x is the ip of the DNS server.

That being said, this shouldn't affect pinging 8.8.8.8, so I would also recommend trying to type:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and see if you get anywhere...

...If you don't, please set to DHCP, type `ifconfig` and paste the full output here, followed by making the changes, typing `ifconfig` and pasting the output here again.